# Highcharts Chart Bubble Resizing

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, bubble-chart

When displaying a Highcharts bubble chart, the bubbles resize as bubbles are added/removed to the chart (each bubble is sized relative to all visible bubbles).  Is there a way to set the max/min bubble range for the chart so that the bubbles are sized relative to those dimensions, allowing them to stay the same size as bubbles are added/removed from the chart?

Here are some bubbles:
[image]

Here, a bubble is added -- which becomes the new smallest bubble (brown) -- causing the purple and turquoise bubbles (smallest in the first image) to resize larger.
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but why was this down-voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Sebastian Bochan, this is the default bubble chart behavior.  In my opinion, this behavior could be improved.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

yes, there's a bubble minSize and maxSize option e.g.

```
     bubble: {
            minSize:5,
            maxSize:30
     }
```

you set it in the plotOptions

Comment: Thanks.  I tried those options.  The bubbles will still resize relative to all visible bubbles regardless what those options are defined as.

Comment: oh dear. then why have them there?

Comment: Those options set the max/min size of the bubbles.  They work and do what they are designed to do.  Those options simply don't address my scenario.

Comment: At this moment this is default behaviour of bubble chart. You can post your suggestion in our uservoice here http://highcharts.uservoice.com